# как добавить элемент в список (list) scala

Tags: list, scala

Первый день начинаю изучать scala.
Есть задача: Написать функцию (рекурсию), которая возвращает новый список, в котором каждый элемент является
суммой предыдущего элемента нового списка и текущего элемента
входного списка. Пример: List(1, 4, 2) преобразуется в List(1, 5, 7)

```
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

var sp1: List[Int] = Nil

def summation(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {

  if (list.isEmpty || list.tail.count(_ == 2) == 0){
   sp1
  }:List[Int]
  else {
   sp1 :+ (list.head + list.tail.head)
   summation(list.tail)
  }
}
summation(mylist)
```

В итоге функция summation() возвращает пустой лист.
Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `List(1, 4, 2).scanLeft(0)(_ + _)`, а ошибок у вас слишком много, чтобы дать какой-то конкретный совет по исправлению ситуации. Продолжайте учить язык до просветления :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List` - [неизменяемая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) (immutable) коллекция, т.е. в неё нельзя добавлять и из неё удалять что-либо.
Вместо этого можно создать новый список с который будет содержать старый список плюс новый элемент.

Для создания списка с новым элементом в конце - оператор `:+`, в начале оператор `+:` либо более популярный `::`.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)

val list2 = list :+ 9 // List(1, 2, 3, 9)
val list3 = 9 +: list // List(9, 1, 2, 3)
val list4 = 9 :: list // List(9, 1, 2, 3)
```

Работа с переменной (`var`) выглядит так:

```
var list = List(1, 2, 3)
list = list :+ 9 // List(1, 2, 3, 9)
// либо сокращённо
list :+= 9 // List(1, 2, 3, 9, 9)
```

И так, в твоём примере есть создание нового списка, но ни в какой переменной результат не сохранён:

```
sp1 = sp1 :+ (list.head + list.tail.head)
// либо
sp1 :+= (list.head + list.tail.head)
```

P.S. Рекомендую пользваться IDE - он может предупредить о неиспользуемом коде. Кроме того, в режиме отладки можно посмотреть как работает программа строка за строкой.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!